# Инкремент это аналог +1?

Tags: javascript

Есть 4 блока, которые поочерёдно меняют и сбрасывают цвет.
Как я понимаю инкремент **(++) это аналог +1, верно?**
**Но почему когда **я пытаюсь заменить инкремент на его аналог +1**, то мои цвета перестают переключатся по 4 блокам.**

```js
let a = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

const colorMenu = [               
{name: 'blue', interval: 1000},     
{name: '', interval: 1000},
{name: 'red', interval: 1000},
{name: '', interval: 1000}
];

let count = 0;
let colorCount = 0;

let go = setTimeout(function change() {
if (count === colorMenu.length) {        
count = 0;
}

if(colorCount === colorMenu.length){     
colorCount = 0; 
}

a[count].style.background = colorMenu[colorCount].name;                                     
go = setTimeout(change,colorMenu[count].interval );       
                                                         
if(colorCount % 2){
count++           // не работает, если заменить на его аналог + 1
};
 
colorCount++      // не работает, если заменить на его аналог + 1
 
},1000);
```

```css
body{   
user-select:none;
}

.main{
margin-top:100px;
margin-left:200px;  
width:250px;
height: 100px;  
background: blue;
}

.item{
height: 100%;   
background: gray;   
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "main">
<div class = "item" data-color='red'>1</div>
<div class = "item" data-color='blue'>2</div>
<div class = "item" data-color='orange'>3</div>
<div class = "item" data-color='gold'>4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы меняете

```
count++
```

на

```
count + 1
```

а надо на

```
count = count + 1;
```

или на

```
count += 1;
```

Comment: Спасибо, я уже реально тупить начал =)

Comment: count = count + 1 более понятно для понимания и чтения, чем count++ Для какой цели нужны инкременты, ведь они иногда сбивают с толку.

Comment: @ЯнЗамойский Это позволяет одновременно изменять переменную и использовать ее значение до/после изменения.

Comment: Понятно, ставлю +++